# Preprocessor check for availability of Winsockets / BSD sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, winsockets, berkeley-sockets

I'm new to socket programming and want to make a cross platform app (C++) that supports both windows and unix systems.

The default on for websocket transport on Windows seems to be windows sockets while on unix systems it's BSD sockets. So how can I decide at preprocessor time which sockets are available so I can abstract away this layer? Is there a definition which I can check which also corresponds to the availability of these features?

I thought about checking the `_WIN32` and `__unix__` definitions but those are platform definitions and I'm not sure if they necessarily correspond to the availability of a *feature*. I guess this is very well the case for Windows systems but I heard that some unix systems will only offer partial BSD socket compliance so this check could be misleading?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm new to socket programming and want to make a cross platform app (C++) that supports both windows and unix systems.

There are numerous cross-platform socket libraries that are already available.

> The default on for websocket transport on Windows seems to be windows sockets while on unix systems it's BSD sockets.

Winsock includes BSD-compatible socket functions that are mostly API-compatible with other platforms (there are some differences). The biggest difference you will have to deal with is in the header files that you will need to `#include` on each platform.

> Is there a definition which I can check which also corresponds to the availability of these features?

No, there is not.

> I thought about checking the `_WIN32` and `__unix__` definitions but those are platform definitions and I'm not sure if they necessarily correspond to the availability of a *feature*.

That is basically what you need to do (and what other cross-platform libraries do).

Comment: Thank you! Idk it would need to be a really lightweight library. Is there such a one?

Comment: I'm sure there are. But asking for library recommendations is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow.  Just search around until you find something that suits your needs.